# Binding Command to Viewmodel with ItemsSource from a StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, itemssource

I am trying to add an `ItemsSource` to a `MenuItem` while keeping the Command bound to my ViewModel (my Window's DataContext). So far, I haven't figured out a way to make it work. Before the ItemsSource is added, the binding is fine. The collection that I am trying to bind comes from a `StaticResource`. Can anybody help me out with this?

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenTeamPage}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          Header="Teams"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Teams,
                                Source={StaticResource Container}}" />
```

I have tried using this and variations of it with no luck:

```
Command="{Binding OpenTeamPage,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
                  Mode=Default}"
```

If anybody could tell me how to use this ItemsSource while still binding my Command to my ViewModel, I would greatly appreciate it. I suppose I could put the Command in my Team model, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

EDIT : To clarify my problem, with the ItemsSource in place, the command in the ViewModel doesn't fire at all. Without the ItemsSource, the command fires. I would like to be able to have the ItemsSource and still be able to fire the command.

EDIT:

```
public class GameContainer
{
    static GameContainer()
    {
        Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>();
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; } 
}
```

In App.xaml:

```
<data:GameContainer x:Key="Container" />
```

The collection is populated when the program is started.

My goal once I get this working is to pass the selected team to the Viewmodel, hopefully via CommandParameter, and display info regarding the selected team.

EDIT: I was mistaken in my original post. A bound collection coming from the Viewmodel does not work either.

Comment: do you see child menuitems containing Teams in both case?

Comment: Yes, they display correctly.

Comment: Please also post the definition of your resource `Container`

Comment: are you sure when you bind the ItemsSource of menuitem to VM property, the command on it works?

Comment: I actually just modified my post. I was mistaken when I first wrote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the behaviour of `MenuItem`, Item having Child `MenuItem` won't fire `Command` and it also should not as it does not make sense. But if you still want to fire a command on Parent Item click,there are two options

1. You can use Interactivity Triggers on your MenuItem to call command on MouseDown event like

   ```
   <MenuItem 
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"
         Header="Teams"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Teams,
                               Source={StaticResource Container}}">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
           <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OpenTeamPage}" />
       </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </MenuItem>
   ```
2. you can define a Attached Property for command and define the MenuItem MouseDown behaviour like

   ```
    public static class MouseCommandBehavior
    {

         public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseDownCommandProperty =
                       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseDownCommand",
                       typeof(ICommand),
                       typeof(MouseCommandBehavior),
                       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (obj, e) => OnMouseCommandChanged(obj, (ICommand)e.NewValue, false)));

    public static ICommand GetMouseDownCommand(DependencyObject d)
    {
            return (ICommand)d.GetValue(MouseDownCommandProperty);
    }

     public static void SetMouseDownCommand(DependencyObject d, ICommand value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MouseDownCommandProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnMouseCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, ICommand command)
    {
          if (command == null) return;

           var element = (FrameworkElement)d;

           element.PreviewMouseDown += (obj, e) => command.Execute(null);
     }
    }
   }
   ```

and you can set this Property value on your menuItem

```
<MenuItem local:MouseCommandBehavior.MouseDownCommand="{Binding OpenTeamPage}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      Header="Teams"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Teams,
      Source={StaticResource Container}}">
```

Comment: This certainly seems like a good approach. Seeing as it does what I need for it to do, I'll gladly accept your answer. One thing, though, is that using the `MouseDown` event didn't work for me. This did: `<i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`MenuItem` will not execute its command if it's not a leaf node. Only menu items that are leafs (items with no children) are executing a command.

This is probably done due to convention - when you click an items that has children you get the children shown immediately, otherwise there's a delay from mouse hover till children shown.

Although it's probably a bad idea (from UX point of view) to have command on a parent, it's possible:

```
<MenuItem DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          Header="{Binding OpenTeamPage}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Teams, Source={StaticResource Container}}" >
    <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--Probably need to make this button transparent-->
            <Button Content="Teams"
                    Command="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <!--This style is for the children to fire the same command as the parent-->
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=Header}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Depending upon your design, you'd might need to style the button to be transparent.

Comment: This allows for the parent to fire the command but the children still don't respond when clicked.

Comment: So you need the parent and the children to fire the same command, right? I've edited the answer for that.